# Calling export reports as Pdf for entire dashboard widgets programmatically Cognos

Tags: java, cognos, cognos-8, cognos-bi

Cognos provides option to export each widget in dashboard but not entire dashboard.

My question is that is it possible to export all dashboard widgets as Pdf using cognos sdk for java. 
If not, is there a way to get each widget reports as pdf and then merge it using utility. 
Kindly help on this whether cognos sdk would suit the need..

Comment: You're using Business Insight (or whatever they renamed it to, Cognos Workspace or something?)  If so, those dashboards are intended to be dynamic, you cannot run export it to PDF.  You would have to build a report in Report Studio to do that.

Comment: @Andrew :Yep,..Im using cognos workspace and Thanks for the info.